# Ext Js 4 "white-space" only for one grid in project

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, extjs4

Dear StackOverFlowers )

I am trying to style only one grid in my ExtJs 4 project. I want it to be "multiline" i.e.

```
    .x-grid-row .x-grid-cell-inner {
    white-space: normal;
}
.x-grid-row-over .x-grid-cell-inner {
    font-weight: bold;
    white-space: normal;
}
```

But if I modify css like above, all my grids became multiline. And in general how can I style only one component in project? For example if I want color only one tab in tabpanel (first or second) or color one of accordion titles?

If anyone can help me  I will be really appreciate ^.^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try adding an Id to the control and use it as a selector to filter out unwanted components.
Lets say your grid id is `gridx` use

```
#gridx .x-grid-row .x-grid-cell-inner {
    white-space: normal;
}
#gridx .x-grid-row-over .x-grid-cell-inner {
    font-weight: bold;
    white-space: normal;
}
```

Comment: To avoid collisions it's probably better to assign `cls` to your grid and use that instead. Not a big deal though.

Comment: I already did it actually, I have assigned class (cls:'myGrid') to my grid but it did not work.